# Creating DateTime object with DateTime::createFromFormat() fails

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have been given a date string from an API in the format e.g.

```
20120522T143127
```

I am trying to convert this to a DateTime object, but the object creation fails because of the 'T' (I think).

This is my current code:

```
$date   = DateTime::createFromFormat( "YMDTHis", '20120522T143127' );
$result = $date->format( $format );
```

What am I missing?

I also tried:

```
$date   = DateTime::createFromFormat( "YMD\THis", '20120522T143127' );
```

Comment: Can you tell why this T is there?

Comment: Returned datetime formatting from calling an API - out of my hands.

Comment: check `@Rizer` answer.

Comment: You have `YMD` when you need to have `Ymd`. And btw: this is standard format, so just use `new DateTime('20120522T143127')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format is a bit wrong:

- **M**    A short textual representation of a month, three letters    **Jan through Dec**

  - Use **m** instead of **M**
  - **m**   Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   **01 through 12**
- **D**    A textual representation of a day, three letters    Mon through Sun

  - Use **d** instead of **D**
  - **d**   Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros   **01 to 31**
- Just escape the **T** with a backslash

So just use:

```
Ymd\THis
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('20120522T143127'));
```